# Ada: Preconditions Error during a test on an other procedure

Tags: ada, preconditions

I'm a little confused. I'm trying to make a generic package to use arrays. The thing is, when I try to test **Initialiser** I get an error: `SYSTEM.ASSERTIONS.ASSERT_FAILURE` on **Get_Element_Indice** and I don't get why it acts like this!

There is the specs (at least some part of them).

```ada
-- Spécification du module Tableau.

generic
Capacite : Integer;   -- Nombre maximal d'éléments qu'un tableau peut contenir
type T_Element is private;  -- Type des éléments du tableau

package Tableaux is

type T_Tableau is limited private;

procedure Initialiser (Tab : out T_Tableau) with
    Post => Get_Taille(Tab)= 0;

function Get_Taille (Tab : in T_Tableau) return Integer with
       Post => Get_Taille'Result >= 0;

function Get_Element_Indice (Tab : in T_Tableau ; Indice : in Integer) return T_Element ;
       Pre => Indice > 0 and Get_Taille(Tab) >= Indice; --This is where the error is located according to gnat's debuger.

procedure Modifier_Element (Tab : in out T_Tableau; Indice : in Integer; N_Valeur : in T_Element) with
        Pre => Get_Taille(Tab) >= Indice and Indice > 0,
        Post => Get_Element_Indice(Tab, Indice) = N_Valeur;

-- There are more procedures but the error is above so I've cleaned them.

private

type T_Tab_Elements is array (1..Capacite) of T_Element;

type T_Tableau is
    record
        Elements : T_Tab_Elements;  -- les éléments du tableau
        Taille: Integer;            -- Nombre d'éléments dans le tableau
    end record;
   end Tableaux;`
```

Here you can find the body:

```ada
-- Implantation du module Tableau.
package body Tableaux is

procedure Initialiser (Tab : out T_Tableau) is
begin
    Tab.Taille := 0;
end Initialiser;

function Get_Taille (Tab : in T_Tableau) return Integer is
begin
    Return Tab.Taille;
end Get_Taille;

function Get_Element_Indice (Tab : in T_Tableau ; Indice : in Integer) return T_Element is
begin
       return Tab.Elements(Indice);
end Get_Element_Indice;


-- It goes on ..

end Tableaux;
```

And here is the test:

```ada
with Tableaux;

-- Programme de test du module Tableaux.
procedure Test_Tableaux is

package Tableaux_Charactere is
        new Tableaux (Capacite => 10, T_Element => Character);
use Tableaux_Charactere;


function Test_Fonction_Element (Element : in Character) return Character is
    pragma Unreferenced (Element); -- Also, if someone could explain why do I need this line it would be great =)
begin
    return 'A';
end Test_Fonction_Element;


 procedure Appliquer_Sur_Chaque_Charactere is new Appliquer_Sur_Chaque(Test_Fonction_Element);


 -- Initialiser un tableau avec "OK" ajoutés dans le tableau vide.
    procedure Initialiser_Avec_OK (Tab : out T_Tableau) is
begin
    Initialiser(Tab);
    Ajouter_Element(Tab, 'O');
    Ajouter_Element(Tab, 'K');
end Initialiser_Avec_OK;


 -- Initialiser un tableau avec "BONJOUR" ajoutés dans le tableau vide.
procedure Initialiser_Avec_BONJOUR (Tab : out T_Tableau) is
begin
    Initialiser (Tab);
    Ajouter_Element(Tab, 'B');
    Ajouter_Element(Tab, 'O');
    Ajouter_Element(Tab, 'N');
    Ajouter_Element(Tab, 'J');
    Ajouter_Element(Tab, 'O');
    Ajouter_Element(Tab, 'U');
    Ajouter_Element(Tab, 'R');
end Initialiser_Avec_BONJOUR;


-- Test de l'initialisation du Tableau
procedure Tester_Initialiser is
    Tab, Tab2 : T_Tableau;
begin
    Put("Test intialiser");
    Initialiser_Avec_BONJOUR(Tab2);
    pragma Assert ( Get_Taille(Tab2) = 7);
    Initialiser(Tab);
    pragma Assert (Get_Taille(Tab) = 0);
end Tester_Initialiser;

begin
Tester_Initialiser; -- Procedure I want to test
-- There are more
 end Test_Tableaux;
```

I want to apologize for my broken English, it's not my native language. Thanks for your help !

Comment: You’ve supplied lots of code, but it doesn’t compile. I inserted the missing `with` in the spec of `Get_Element_Indice`. I made up an `Ajouter_Element` and commented out the spec of `Modifier_Element` (whose body is missing) because it never gets called. Then, it builds & runs to completion, **without showing your problem**; because **your test program doesn’t actually call `Get_Element_Indice`**. It’s always a good idea to make sure that the code you post compiles and shows the problem you’re asking about.

Answer (score 0):

The default exception you get when an assertion fails is `Ada.Assertions.Assertion_Error`.

The package `System.Assertions` is not a part of the standard, so it looks like you may have found a bug in the compiler.  (A complete reproducer in the question would be helpful to verify this.)

Comment: In GNAT, `Ada.Assertions.Assertion_Error` is a renaming of `System.Assertions.Assert_Failure`. This is permitted ([ARM 11.4.2(24)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-11-4-2.html#p24))

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't noticed that.  My initial impression is that it is one of the less thought-through - and more confusing - implementation permissions in the LRM.